When solving the Dirichlet problem on an $n$-cube using separation of variables, how does one prove continuity of the solution?
I want to understand how to find harmonic functions on an $n$-cube with Dirichlet boundary condition, using the method of separation of variables. This is described, for example, here: https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~grigoryan/124B/lecs/lec9.pdf (described there only in the case of 2 or 3 dimensions; but it seems easy to generalise to higher dimensions). This method involves searching for solutions with separated variables, and then summing them up with appropriate coefficients, based on the Fourier coefficients of the boundary condition $f$ on the faces. This method is also described in many other sources all over the internet, including textbooks and lecture notes.
However, none of the sources seem to discuss the continuity of the obtained solution. It is clear to me that the solution we obtain is harmonic (and hence continuous) on the interior of the region. However, when solving the Dirichlet problem we have to find a function that is continuous on the closed region (in this case, the closed $n$-cube), i.e., a harmonic function that approaches the values prescribed by the boundary condition as we approach the boundary. Without that, we can not even say that the harmonic function obtained with this method has anything to do with the boundary condition.
I understand that if the function $f$ on the boundary is sufficiently smooth, the Fourier series converges absolutely, and the obtained solution is continuous as a uniform limit of continuous functions. However, for this to work the function has to be smooth when restricted to the corresponding face of the cube and tiled all over its hyperplane in a periodic fashion (as a simple example, function $g(x)=x$ is not smooth in terms of taking its Fourier series because if we make it periodic by restricting it to $(-\pi, \pi]$ it acquires a discontinuity at the point $\pi$). This means, in particular, that the Fourier series would converge absolutely only if the restriction of $f$ to each $(n-1)$-dimensional face has equal values when restricted to each pair of its opposite $(n-2)$-dimensional faces. For example, in the case of a rectangle, it would simply mean that the values of $f$ in all the four corners are the same. But this does not hold for general $f$.
So, how do I prove the continuity of the solution to Dirichlet problem on an $n$-cube which is obtained with the method of separation of variables?
